# react js Input fields not updating after successful array update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of a input fields, dynamically generated by an array that are intended to be populated by default with a '?'. Once a user enters a letter into one of the inputs, the `onchange` event should fire and the array updates successfully, repopulating the inputs with the updated values. As of now, if I provide a `value={letter}` as an attribute, the inputs populate as expected, but the array that populates the inputs does not update. If I take `value={letter}` out, the array updates as expected, but the inputs of course, don't populate.

```js
const [letters, setLetters] = useState(workLetters);
function inputChangeHandler(event) {
  const incomingLetter = event.target.value;
  const nextLetters = [...letters];
  letters.forEach((letter, idx) => {
    if (letters_rec_of_truth[idx] === incomingLetter) {
      nextLetters[idx] = incomingLetter;
    }
  });
  console.log("next letters is now " + nextLetters);
  setLetters(nextLetters);
}
useEffect(() => {}, [letters]);
console.log("letters is now " + letters);
//  console.log(evt);

return (
  <div>
    {letters.map((letter, idx) => {
      return (
        <input
          type="text"
          key={idx}
          value={letter}
          onChange={inputChangeHandler}
        ></input>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Try using a unique identifier for keys because it's not recommended to use indexes for keys https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: What is `letters_rec_of_truth`? Also, how are you verifying that the array foes not update?

Comment: Code seems basically OK to me. Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why instead of 'value' dont you use 'defaultValue' for the 'input' tag?

Comment: I thought I did this, but I saw your comment, retried it and it worked. Thanks.